# Python Datatype for a fixed-length FIFO

Tags: python

I would like to know if there is a native datatype in Python that acts like a fixed-length FIFO buffer.  For example, I want do create a length-5 FIFO buffer that is initialized with all zeros.  Then, it might look like this:

[0,0,0,0,0]

Then, when I call the put function on the object, it will shift off the last zero and put the new value, say 1, into the left side:

[1,0,0,0,0]

If I put a 2, it would then shift and put to look like this:

[2,1,0,0,0]

...and so on.  The new value goes at the front and the oldest one is shifted off.  I understand that this would be very easy to implement myself, but I would like to use native python datatypes if at all possible.  Does anyone know which datatype would be best for this?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

```
x = collections.deque(5*[0], 5)
```

See [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html?highlight=collections.deque#collections.deque) for more about `collections.deque`; the method you call `push` is actually called `appendleft` in that type.

The second parameter (`maxlen`, giving the maximum lengths) was added in Python 2.6; if you're using older versions of Python, it won't be available.

Answer (score 15):

you can also use list

```
a = [0,0,0,0,0]

a.pop(0)
a.append(1)

print a
result [0,0,0,0,1]
```

or for left side in right out, otherwise

```
a.pop(5)
a.insert(0,1)
print a
result [1,0,0,0,0]
```

Comment: -1 This is not recommended. For reason why read the docs http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html?highlight=collections.deque#collections.deque

Comment: @toom it isn't not recommended, you just need to be aware of the penalty of using lists. For simplicity, a list is hard to beat.

Comment: This is a bad solution. I implemented it using a list with a fixed number of elements and an index counter.

Comment: -1 first example is not a FIFO, it is a LIFO. The second example it is indeed a FIFO, although it's an extremely slow one and not recommented. collections.deque is a much faster one, with O(1) complexity for appendleft, instead of list.seek(0,1) which has complexity equal to list length.

Answer (score 9):

Just one more example to this post

```
from collections import deque

domains = ['1.com','2.com','3.com']
d = deque(domains)               
d.pop() #pop(delete) 3.com here
d.appendleft('new.com') 


print d
```

result:

```
deque(['new.com', '1.com', '2.com'])
```

Comment: Why you use pop and not maxlen ?

Comment: I'ts not what's happening in this example, but you may want to catch the item that falls off the buffer. For that, use pop: `fell_off = d.pop(); d.appendleft(new)`.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `deque` function:

```
from collections import deque 

test_queue = deque([0]*5,maxlen=5) 

test_queue = deque([0]*5,maxlen=5) 

for i in range(10):
    print(i)
    test_queue.appendleft(i)
    print(list(test_queue))
```

prints:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
1
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
2
[2, 1, 0, 0, 0]
3
[3, 2, 1, 0, 0]
4
[4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
5
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
6
[6, 5, 4, 3, 2]
7
[7, 6, 5, 4, 3]
8
[8, 7, 6, 5, 4]
9
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5]
```