# Trim a list to a maximum number of elements

Tags: python, list, fifo

I would like to remove the oldest-added (i.e. the first) elements of a list, such that this list never exceeds 100 elements.

I thought about:

```
L = [327983, 232382, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 23]

if len(L) > 100:
    for i in range(len(L)-100):
        del L[0]

print L    # [4, 5, 6, 23]
```

**Is there a solution without iteration** (or more generally: a nicer solution) **for trimming the beginning of the list, so that it has <= 100 elements?**

---

*Sidenote: Isn't there something else than lists, for this purpose? i.e. a data structure that has a maximum size, and such that if more data comes, the oldest are deleted! (It makes me think about FIFO? Stack? Pipe?)*

Comment: Of course FIFO is best for this (Queue).

Comment: [Python Datatype for a fixed-length FIFO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931589/python-datatype-for-a-fixed-length-fifo)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just assign a slice back to your list

```
L = L[-100:]
```

Answer (score 8):

How about using [`collection.deque`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque)? If you specify `maxlen`, it will not store more than `maxlen` elements.

```
>>> from collections import deque
>>> q = deque([1, 2, 3], maxlen=3)
>>> q
deque([1, 2, 3], maxlen=3)
>>> q.append(4)
>>> q
deque([2, 3, 4], maxlen=3)
```